# Select entries starting with same letter from alphabet list

Tags: search, conditional

I have a list of all my games using pagination. It works great:
http://www.colorcomputergames.com/games

However, I'd like to add links at the top of the page like:
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z

And so I want to be able to click on any letter and display only entries starting with that letter.

I was was going to make a template for every page but that seems inefficient.

How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you should create a [dynamic route](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) (something like `"games/glossary/<slug>"`) and point it to a template. A dynamic route means you won't have to create a template for every letter. Note the use of the `<slug>` token, which – although not entirely semantic – should do nicely in this case.

In your template, you'll need to pull the letter from the URL. Note that it's also a good idea to test if the variable is a single character, and in the a-z range (i.e. a valid letter, and not some other entity).

```
{% set letter = slug is defined and slug|length == 1 and slug matches '/^[a-z]/i' ? slug %}
```

If there is no valid letter in the `slug` variable, it's a good idea to throw a 404:

```
{% if not letter %}
  {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

Next, you can actually use [search syntax](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching#supported-syntaxes) for the `title` parameter (specifically, a wildcard `*`), in order to pull all entries with a title starting with the relevant letter:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').title(letter~'*').limit(null).order('title asc') %}
```

If you want to throw a 404 whenever there aren't any entries for any given letter, it's simply a matter of testing the `length` property for `entries`:

```
{% if not entries|length %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

If you need [pagination](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate) in your template, it'll work out of the box as usual:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('games').title(letter~'*').limit(10).order('title asc') as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

{% if not pageEntries|length %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{% for entry in pageEntries %}
    ...
```

Comment: That works like a charm!!!!

Comment: Only thing not working is going to a letter without entries doesn't give me the 404. Need to ponder where to place your snippet as I also have pagination code in my template.

Comment: If you're doing pagination, you'll probably need to use a named token in your dynamic route, because with pagination the page number will be the last segment in the URL, not the letter. For the 404 issue, it's simply a matter of testing the length of the returned entries. Updated my answer on both counts.